# Retaining OLD index after doing full-import of NEW Index in SOLR..?

Tags: import, solr, command, indexing

I am using SOLR 3.5.0..!!

I have made two Indexes : "**Cars**" and "**Vendors**"

Both indexes fetch results from the Database and populate Documents..!!

My request handlers are as follows :

```
    <requestHandler name="/selectCars" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">solr/jcoreDocuments/CarsConfig.xml</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>

     <requestHandler name="/selectVendors" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">solr/jcoreDocuments/vendorConfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
     </requestHandler>
```

Now when i hit the following URL :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/selectVendors?command=full-import
```

It fetches the corresponding `47531` documents..!!

when i hit : `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*` ....
It shows that i have `47531` documents available..!! (THATS CORRECT)

Now when i want to fetch my "**Cars**" documents, but retaining the "**Vendor**" documents..I hit the following URL :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/selectCars?command=full-import&clean=false
```

It shows that it has fetched corresponding `802` documents..!!

Now when i hit `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*` ....I still have `47531` documents available ..!!

(But now it contains `802` **NEW** - **Cars** documents and **REDUCED** `46729` **Vendors** documents )

---

**Note** : After fetching two Indexes the total documents should be `47531` + `802` = `48333`

---

How is it possible...Am i missing something..??

Comment: Could you add requestHandler configuration for "select"? And maybe how yours ids for cars and vendors look like?

Comment: I have not configured `/select` in my **SolrConfig.xml**..It is configured by default in Solr 3.5.0..!!

Comment: My default Request Handler is "Search" .. `<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">` ..!!

Comment: Is it possible that the IDs of your documents in the `cars` core duplicate IDs of the documents in the `vendors` core?

Comment: Yeah..!!..they are from different Tables in the database..So there IDs can be same...!!..So should i use some kinda template transformer to make unique IDs..?? ..or is there any other nice method..??

Comment: Would it be possible to prepend the table name to the ID (so that you have, say, 'cars1', 'cars2', 'vendor1', 'vendor2', etc.)? I think by default the uid in Solr is stored as a string, but if not, then you'll want to modify your schema.xml. You probably won't want to use a UUID as that would prevent your being able to update documents one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are reindexing data with the same ID would be "updated" that might mean your vendors would become cars. In your dataimport conf change id to they will be unique for vendors and cars